# How can I preserve the uppercase/lower case of a string in search using perl?

Tags: perl

I want to search for "**F**requencies" (its first letter in uppercase) in my text files. And my code will print to the output file some columns including "Frequencies". But there are also occurrences of "**f**requencies" (its first letter in lowercase) in the text files. I am using this part `$search_word = qr/Frequencies/;` in the code. How can I make the first letter of the word "Frequencies" upper case in the `$search_word = qr/Frequencies/;` part to eliminate the occurrences of "**f**requencies" in the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, you have [ucfirst](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html) to capitalize the first letter. For example:

```
$a = "freQuEncY";
$a = ucfirst(lc($a));  # $a <-- "Frequency";
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use regex match to check , like this

```
 if($string_to_be_searched =~ /Frequencies/){
  do something; # like print
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
if ( $$test_string[$i] =~ /\b(?i)f(?-i)requencies/ ) {
    my $captured = ucfirst($&);
    # process $captured
}
```

Explanation:

- The regex matches will be case-insensitive for the first letter of the word `frequencies` only. `(?i)` turns on case-insensitive matching at the position it occurs for the remainder of the pattern or until it is revoked by `(?-i)`. This works for other flags too, cf. [perldoc section on re](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).
- `$&` contains the full match
- `\b` denotes a word boundary (perhaps you don't need that but your problem description suggests you do).